3 pin molex shower fan connector, what should I do?


This fan does not work, is it possible to replace this? Most of the units I see online two prong connectors

it depends if that green and white striped wire is a ground or not.

what does does not work mean? ... what is wrong with the fan?

Make and model of fan?  Checked with manufacturer?
